# Is it possible to change a form input type from text to email in wtforms without javascript?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using flask-wtforms to submit an email form. I haven't found any documentation saying that wtforms has an `EmailField()` type, and I get an error saying it cannot be imported when I try to use it. When I try to change the form type in the template (ex.
`{{ form.email(type="email", class="form") }}`) the change to the type gets ignored and it gets rendered as `type="text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try..

(you haven't posted any code, so i'm posting a simple example of a form `class` setup to include Email and Validation)

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import EmailField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email
```

```
class YourForm(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField('Email address', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Email()])
```

Comment: the above answer is based on examples from previous projects of mine that are currently working. if this doesn't do the trick, post your code, and we'll keep working on it. good luck! hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I could not for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: always glad to help!